# CANNOT_CREATE_DEPRECATED_ADS Error while calling Google ads rest API

Tags: rest, google-ads-api

I am trying to create ads in Google using REST Api. As per the REST API documentation passing the following request body.

```
{
"operations": [
    {
        "create": {
            "adGroup": "customers/*********/adGroups/*********",
            "status": "PAUSED",
            "ad": {
                "expandedTextAd": {
                    "headlinePart1": "Example heading",
                    "headlinePart2": "Exmaple heading 2",
                    "description": "Sample description about ad"
                },
                "finalUrls": [
                    "https://www.example.com"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
],
"partialFailure": false,
"validateOnly": true
}
```

Endpoint: [https://googleads.googleapis.com/v11/customers/{customer_id}/adGroupAds:mutate](https://googleads.googleapis.com/v11/customers/%7Bcustomer_id%7D/adGroupAds:mutate)

Anyone can suggest what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google stopped [creating](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7056544?hl=en) extended text ads instead we can use Responsive text ads.